# Dynamic 2d terrain loading / stitching in Unity

Tags: 2d, unity, terrain

I'm currently working on a top down 2d game (in Unity 2d) where I'd like to build a huge terrain for the player to explore.
My question is - do you have any good practices or ideas on how to chunk the terrain, work on it in Unity (should I work on terrain chunks in different scenes etc.) and finally load it dynamically and efficiently in runtime ?

Comment: This question is too broad to be specifically answerable here - terrain streaming is a huge topic.  If I google "unity terrain streaming" there seems to be a lot out there, so I'd recommend you to read up what other people have done first, then ask here if you have a more specific question.

Comment: That's true, theres a lot of stuff on google on map generation, however what I probably wanted most to get opinion on is what approach to take for a strategy for map generation for top down 2d game specificaly in Unity. As I'm pretty new to Unity, I'm not sure whether I should use Terrain, meshes or assemble the whole map in unity as a scene to best fit 2d top down view. I know it's a broad question, still any insight here would be priceless.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make it with a grid where you place new terrain tiles as necessary. See here for an explanation and a simple TerrainManager: http://upshift.org/2012/02/building-endless-terrain-in-unity3d/